# wrapping a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using numpy arrays in python and am trying to better visualize them to see what I am working with. Is there a way to change when the array wraps to the next line?
For instance, in the terminal window I have enough columns to show 0-49 on one line, but it automatically wraps on me when I convert to an array data type.

```
>>> tmp.shape
(2, 50)
>>> print tmp
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
  48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73
  74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97
  98 99]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Numpy by default prints only 75 characters when displaying arrays. You can change this by using numpy.set_printoptions()

For eg. I set my terminal to display 132x43 and got this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.set_printoptions(linewidth=132)
>>> a = np.arange(100).reshape(2,50)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
   [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
    81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Comment: Why is there a big gap between 18 and 19?